# WPF KeyBinding - Enter + 0

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, keypress, key-bindings

I want to assign to the command call -"Enter+0". How to do it with KeyBinding ? Something like this:

```
  <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="D0"
                Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                Modifiers="Enter" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I use MVVM Ligth, so I want to make it with the command. The command is in ViewModel, KeyBinding in View. "Enter+0" - used in the previous version program.

Comment: `Enter` is not a [modifier key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx). Are you trying to detect Enter and 0 being pressed at the same time?

Comment: `Enter+0` that's one weird key-binding.

Comment: I use MVVM Ligth, so I want to make it with the command. The command is in ViewModel, KeyBinding in View. "Enter+0" - used in the previous version pragram.

Comment: KeyBinding has nothing to do with MVVM. You can still in your view have you View's code-behind detect when your "Enter+0" is invoked and using the `Messenger` in MVVM Light send a message to the VM that indicates the corresponding Command needs to be invoked.

Comment: How to identify pressing these keys?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work with an behaviour binded to an particular UI-Element (Button, DropdownBox,...) and checking if another KeyDown Event is active at the same time.